# Pass dynamic choice list to form from Views in class based views

Tags: django, dynamic, django-views, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I just want to pass a list which will look like this from views to form , FYI i'm using MultipleChoiceField

```
[('ad7d4d7c5fbd4678bafd9f2b93fdd4b5', 'Chandrayaan'), ('b55d7c02c29d4501b8d3f63053fef470', 'MOM'), ('b90a66ea9eb24d019102fadde900fdda', 'Galactica')]
```

i have another issue related to this question as well which i have posted already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149576/select-a-valid-choice-6da87c51321849bdb7da80990fdab19b-is-not-one-of-the-availa)

Comment: Where do these options originate from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a dynamic choice field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419997/creating-a-dynamic-choice-field)

Comment: @DivitRao: likely if these originate from a model, you can make use of a `ModelChoiceField`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i did used `ModelChoiceField` but still it shows me 'Select a valid choice. *value* is not one of the available choices'     [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69149576/select-a-valid-choice-6da87c51321849bdb7da80990fdab19b-is-not-one-of-the-availa)